# How to solve a differential equation involving spring constants?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A spring with a spring constant $k$ of $320$ Newtons per meter is loaded with a $5$-kg weight and allowed to reach equilibrium. It is then displaced $1$ meter downward and released. If the weight experiences a damping force in Newtons equal to $64$ times the velocity at every point, find the equation of motion.

$y(t)= ?$

where $t$ is time and $y(t)$ is displacement in time.

So I found that the characteristic equation would be; 
$$5r^2 + 64r + 320 = 0$$

and I solved that equation for its roots which are: 
$r = -(32/5) + (24/5)i$ and $-(32/5) - (24/5)i$

So the general equation would be: 
$$c_1e^{-32t/5} \cos(24t/5) + c_2e^{-32t/5} \sin(24t/5) = y(t)$$

The only initial condition I can pull from the problem is $y(0) = 1$ which tells me that $c_1=1$ but I do not know how to find $c_2$.

Are there more initial conditions in the problem or is my method wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the derivative, to calculate the velocity as a function of time. The weight is released from rest, so $y'(t=0)=0$